# How to maintain global state?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating an editor for a custom file type with the usual operations like New, Open, Savem, and Save As.

The problem is that I don't know how to give every Form access to the same data. I want a Form to show the data, another Form to edit it and another form to add new data to the database.

Is it best to use a Database-Class that is marked as "public static" so that everything can access the database directly?  Or should I pass a reference to the main form and have a "Database"-variable declared in there.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what are you having trouble with specifically?

Comment: A crude way is for each file to have `bool` which tracks if there are unsaved changes. How to set or reset it depends on what ways you have for the users to edit the projects.

Comment: Moti Azu I hope I made everything more clear

Comment: I edited my question to clarify my problem.

Comment: Your title does not make any sense. And the body makes a little. "*I want to create an IDE for a custom filetype. I need the basic operations like New, Open, Save, Save as and so on.*" to "*How should I structure this? How do I know, if there is a project currently opened?*", is such a great I doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks! Maybe it is better this time? I appreciate your help, everybody!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Well, it is better, but still way to broad IMO. At least for SO. If OP wants genereal ideas this is not the best place to ask IMO. After all the editing I also think the OP is not some lazy bum, but the wording really made it unanswerable. Now it's way clearer.

Comment: I edited to clarify more; and added the windows forms tag (you mentioned forms, please change if this was incorrect). Feel free to reivew/rollback. Also, while probably not an answer, consider using WPF and the MVVM pattern here.

Comment: @luk32 The intent is potentially too broad; but I imagine the specific question of "How do I give access to the database, with a parameter or global object" is narrow enough. The answer could then give a better alternative if they so chose.

Comment: Would it be possible to open the question again?

Comment: @user2523584 You need 5 members of the community to vote to reopen. You have 2 (including me) as of this comment posting. Nothing to do now but wait. While you do so; do some research on MVVM :)

Comment: Thank you, will do so! The MVVM is a pattern, right? So i can use it with WinForms? I would rather use WinForms than WPF.

Comment: Its a pattern; so it *technically* would work with WinForms; though that tech isn't well suited for the pattern. WPF was practically *made* to work with MVVM, so its a lot easier to go that route.

Comment: And is there a "simple" way of making something like MVVM work with WinForms?

Comment: @user2523584 Not to my knowledge. Winforms has logic/view very tightly coupled. There *are* bindings in WinForms; but I don't know how universally available they are (or how to make them work). In WPF; almost *anything* can be bound.